# C and pointer in a function - changes do not save

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have this simple code that seems to work (I checked with the debugger) but when the function execution ends, the string is not saved in the original variable.

```
void getString(char *iText);

int main()
{
    char *inputText=malloc(sizeof(char));
    getString(inputText);
    puts(inputText);
    free(inputText);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}


void getString(char *iText)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;

    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        iText = realloc(iText,sizeof(char)*(i+1));
        iText[i]=c;
        i++;
    }

    iText = realloc(iText, sizeof(char)*(i+1));  
    iText[i]='\0';
}
```

When this little script ends, I see some

> ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■▲יע`*

If I write this code in my main function it's working, so I'm guessing it's something to do with the way I'm using the pointer in the function.

Comment: Just let `getString` **return** the pointer, that's much simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getString` takes a pointer by value so cannot change the caller's pointer.  Pass a pointer to a pointer if you want to reallocate the string

```
int main()
{
    ....
    getString(&inputText);
    ....
}

void getString(char **iText)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        *iText = realloc(*iText, i+1);
        (*iText)[i]=c;
        i++;
    }

    *iText = realloc(*iText, i+1);  
    (*iText)[i]='\0';
}
```

I've made one other small change to your code - `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 so the `realloc` calculations can be simplified

Comment: Thanks! I've tired it before but it didn't work as well. Now I tried with the `(*iText)` as you wrote, and it worked!

Comment: @simonc, but if *inputText is a char pointer, then inputText is the address (from whatever rudimentary knowledge of pointers I have), so shouldn't this call actually modify the value at that position? (The answer to which is the OP itself) but I was hoping to clear a few concepts here now that it's up here.

Comment: @varevarao passing `char*` allows you to modify the contents of a `char` array.  If you want to change the array pointed to, you need a pointer to a `char` array - `char**`

Comment: @simonc, oh dang! I misunderstood the whole point of the question. For a moment I thought all the programs I wrote using pointers till date were a big lie! :D Thanks.

Comment: Could also have used a reference to pointer: `void getString(char *&iText)`

Comment: @BokMcDonagh That'd be a valid work C++ solution but the OP tagged the question as C

Comment: @simonc True, didn't notice that this was for C :/